# Optimizing Cesium tile display performance

Tags: cesiumjs

for an interactive project I have created a Cesium viewer instance with two TileMapServiceImageryProvider intances which get their content from a fast local ssd.
Howerver, the display performance when zooming in or out is not very smooth.
It sometimes takes more then a second to display the new content. 
I already turned the requestRenderMode on to increase performance of the whole project but I could ot find any way to speed up tile loading / rendering.
Is there a way to optimize Cesiums tile-handling? Is caching an issue maybe?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Open the network tab in the browser dev tools. Are you being limited by maximum concurrent pending requests? Edge has a higher limit for this than Firefox or Chrome also.

Comment: No. There is no limitation visible.

Comment: Can you describe the issue more clearly in terms of what you’re seeing? What does the problem look like on the screen?

Comment: Well, if you zoom in, it takes a while ( up to two seconds )  before the new tiles appear.

Answer (score 1):

You could increase `tileCaheSize` value

```
viewer.scene.globe.tileCacheSize = 1000; // default 100
```

Also increasing value of maximumScreenSpaceError could help (but with increasing value  image tile quality is decreased)

```
viewer.scene.globe.maximumScreenSpaceError = 5;
```

Comment: It is conventional method. There are unconventional    with decreasing frequency calling render request inside cesium core.  It requires global changes of cesium  scripts  but provides  much more significant results.